# Cartesian product of two lists in python letters and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

current

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

Desired

```
list 3 = [['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['B', 1], ['B', 2],['B', 3],
 ['C', 1], ['C', 2], ['C', 3]]
```

What I have tried

```
list3 = [l+str(n) for l in list1 for n in list2]
```

results in:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
```

Comment: Why not just use `itertools.product`?

Comment: `list3 = [[l,str(n)] for l in list1 for n in list2]` note the brackets around the first part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
[[l,n] for l in list1 for n in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[l]+[n] for l in list1 for n in list2]
```

Answer (score -1):

As Mark has already mentioned, itertools.product would be the way to go. But if you want to continue to use a list comprehension, the correct line would be

```
list3 = [ [l, str(n)] for l in list1 for n in list2 ]
```